# Как отобразить определенную часть изображения в ImageView?

Tags: android, picasso, android-imageview

У меня есть список фотографий, который я отображаю в `ListView` с помощью адаптера.

Сейчас я отображаю фото таким образом:

```
PhotoAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_photo_item, viewGroup, false);

            viewHolder = new PhotoAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (PhotoAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        picasso.load(photo.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.bg_small_11)
                .into(viewHolder.image);
```

Это обычное отображение. А у меня стоит задача отобразить фото по указанным координатам (левая верхняя, правая верхняя, левая нижняя и  правая нижняя точка). То есть я не хочу отображать всё фото, а только этот кусок фото, который пользователь раньше выбрал как превью, и я хочу отображать именно его. Сервер мне возвращает полностью всё фото + координаты (в PX) этого превью. Кто, что может посоветовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод transform и интерфейс Transformation позволяют изменить изображение как душе угодно:

```
picasso.load(photo.getImageUrl())
       .placeholder(R.drawable.bg_small_11)
       .transform(new Transformation {

            @Override public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
                Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height);
                if (result != source)
                   source.recycle();
                return result;
            }

           @Override public String key() { return "crop()"; }
        })
        .into(viewHolder.image);
```

Comment: Да, более логичный способ чем через `Target`.

Comment: Не знаю как у вас, но у меня `transform` иногда не работает. Но этот вариант лучше отмеченного - меньше кода и более читабельно

Comment: этот вариант тоже работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно получить `Bitmap` и создать его обрезанную версию. У вручную установить в `ImageView`. С Picasso это можно сделать примерно так:

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(photo.getImageUrl())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.bg_small_11)
        .into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        bitmap, xCoord, yCoord, width, height); // Координаты, полученные с сервера

                viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: А разве метод `resize` в `Picasso` не подходит?

Comment: Метод `resize`, как похоже из названия, изменяет размер исходного изображения. А тут нужен кроп.

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает как раз как мне нужно!

Comment: Ой, точно, сглупил

Comment: @PonomarenkoOleh Лучше используйте вариант из соседнего ответа с `transform`. Он более правильный.